# System.OperationCanceledException occurs occassionally in async function with try catch

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

All,

I have a production ASP.NET core 2.2 application managing websockets connections. Very occasionally we get exception unhandled errors inside a try catch block if a client resets the connection during transmission, which should be a condition we can handle in code (we disconnect the client).

The try catch block in the code below isn't catching the occasional client disconnect / resets as the error is in CoreLib.dll not the C# code, I suspect it might have to do with not setting up async function correctly??

Any ideas what is causing it, and how to work around it?

```
    // Process web sockets request
    private static async Task<bool> ReceiveBin(MQTT.Broker myClient, CancellationToken ct = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[RECV_BUFF_SIZE]);

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            WebSocketReceiveResult result = null;
            try
            {
                do
                {
                    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    result = await myClient.socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, ct);  <== Unhandled exception breaks here
                    ms.Write(buffer.Array, buffer.Offset, result.Count);
                }
                while (!result.EndOfMessage);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)                                                                            // v1 ASP Core sometimes throw errors when client aborts session
            {
                CloseWSSess(myClient, "Error receiving from client - resetting session. Error: " + ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
   ...
   Error from the await statement => An exception of type 'System.OperationCanceledException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
```

Comment: Hi Deandob, How did you call the async method? Did you cancel it somewhere?

Comment: No, I didn't cancel but the client dropped the connection (which is a normal state of affairs). The async method is called on this line: result = await myClient.socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, ct)

Comment: Hmm. I think your code is OK. Maybe in side the myClient.socket.ReceiveAsync, it request data from your server, and when timeout or something is wrong it will cancel the token and throw that exception.

Comment: myClient.socket.ReceiveAsync is part of the .net framework, which is where this exception is being thrown. I am running it inside VS for testing, so I could turn off the exception checking in VS but I'm concerned that there are unhandled cancellations in the dotnet framework (CoreLib.dll) that may impact this system in production

Comment: Where can I found this: MQTT.Broker. I searched from nuget but I could not found it

Comment: MQTT.Broker is my own class, which wraps an ASP.NET Core websocket that implements ReceiveAsync.

Comment: Also worth noting that this function is part of the websockets middleware I wrote to handle websockets sessions.

Comment: Could you include MTTQ.Broker.Socket.ReceiveAsync() also?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187802/discussion-between-deandob-and-nhan-phan).